# how does sendIn command in ttl file are always being recognized as "unknown command"

Tags: macros, ttl, teraterm

I tried to use batch file to open ttl file through ttermpro.exe,

but once I want to sendIn some string/characters, always pop out `macro error/unknown command window.`

example code:

```
connect '/C=3 /BAUD=57600'
sendIn "ABC"
pause 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong typing of ttl command,

it is sendln not sendIn, how fool i am.